# Upgrade ATI Catalyst Control Center

Tags: ati, software-installation

Twice now an upgrade of the proprietary ATI Catalyst driver has been a major pain, even with the help of [excellent](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide) [guides](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver).

These commands all run successfully (as in `$? -eq 0`):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* \
xorg-driver-fglrx
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper \
debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 \
dh-modaliases # Already installed
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs # Ditto
sudo sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-7-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/natty
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

After a restart it crashed during the graphical boot phase. Restarted in safe mode, and restored the old configuration:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf{.fglrx-N,}
```

Now it boots, and goes straight into the correct video mode, but **the version number shown in CCC still says 11.5!**

Tried uninstalling the drivers, and noticed some warnings:

```
dpkg: warning: while removing fglrx, directory '/usr/lib32/fglrx' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing fglrx, directory '/usr/lib/fglrx/etc/ati' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing fglrx, directory '/usr/lib/fglrx/etc' not empty so not removed.
dpkg: warning: while removing fglrx, directory '/usr/lib/fglrx' not empty so not removed.
```

Tried to install without generating the packages:

```
sudo sh .../ati-driver-installer-11-7-x86.x86_64.run
```

**It says the packages are still installed!** Verified with the following command:

```
$ apt-cache pkgnames --installed | grep fglrx
fglrx
fglrx-dev
fglrx-amdcccle
```

What can I do at this point? I even tried to remove the /usr/lib32/fglrx and /usr/lib/fglrx directories, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know when I have reinstalled fglrx I have usually done what you have done
but slightly differently as I have usually had to go back to the open source versions for a while.

I found this guide to be really helpful

[Ati Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a%20%20Need%20to%20fully%20remove%20-fglrx%20and%20reinstall%20-ati%20from%20scratch)

However this worked for me last time and got rid of pretty much all of the ati/fglrx stuff left on my pc

```
sudo /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh  # (if it exists)


sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

As a further measure I also check what else is left

```
dpkg -l '*fglrx*'
```

and

```
locate fglrx
```

I also make sure I have a correct set of open source drviers installed

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon 
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

I then rebuild the the proprietary fglrx/Catalyst driver to be installable through the Restricted Hardware Driver Manager (a.k.a. jockey)

```
 sudo apt-get install fglrx-modaliases
```

After these have all been completed I reboot and now the open source drviers are working AND xserver-xorg has bene rebuilt I reinstall fglrx

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

That seemed to do the trick last time.

Let us know how you get on

Comment: After running this and installing [Catalyst 11.7](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English) it still says 11.5 in CCC :/

Comment: Rinse, repeat, and it worked! Thanks! A little violent `rm -rf` of the `locate` results was necessary...