# After normal Software Center Updates Unity3D and fglrx stopped working

Tags: fglrx

I was using my System like every day, playing minecraft, watching youtube videos etc.

As usual the software center popped up and asked me to do some updates. I installed them and after an hour i tried to open minecraft, unity crashed.

I still got access to the shell and tried to reboot the system.

After that, I can start unity only in 2d, and fglrx isn't working anymore.

System: Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit, ATI-Radeon HD3850

Here is the jockey.log

```
> 2013-03-02 03:52:32,466 ERROR: Package failed to install:
(Reading database ... 209211 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing fglrx-amdcccle-updates ...
dpkg: warning: while removing fglrx-amdcccle-updates, directory '/usr/share/ati' not empty so not removed.
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx.
(Reading database ... 209166 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx (from .../fglrx_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
One or more files have been altered since installation.
Uninstall will not be completed. See /etc/ati/fglrx-uninstall.log for details.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle (from .../fglrx-amdcccle_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a8.960-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
Error in function:
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

2013-03-02 03:52:32,589 DEBUG: unbind/rebind on driver /sys/module/fglrx/drivers/pci:fglrx_pci: device 0000:01:$
2013-03-02 03:52:32,653 ERROR: XorgDriverHandler.enable(): package or module not installed, aborting
2013-03-02 03:52:32,658 ERROR: xorg:fglrx: get_alternative_by_name(fglrx) returned nothing
2013-03-02 03:52:32,737 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa$
2013-03-02 03:52:32,738 DEBUG: fglrx is not the alternative in use
2013-03-02 03:52:39,594 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa$
2013-03-02 03:52:39,594 DEBUG: fglrx is not the alternative in use
2013-03-02 03:52:39,685 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa$
2013-03-02 03:52:39,686 DEBUG: fglrx is not the alternative in use
2013-03-02 03:52:39,789 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa$
2013-03-02 03:52:39,789 DEBUG: fglrx is not the alternative in use
```

**Addition information**

I found a solution and could repair fglrx with this walkthrough

askubuntu.com/questions/55340/

(no guarantee)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Questions reporting bugs (such as crashes) are off-topic here (see [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)). This should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). You can [make Apport collect and submit the necessary technical info](http://askubuntu.com/a/244982/22949)--but still make sure to read the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first, and describe the problem thoroughly in the bug report you write in the web browser (which will come up automatically after Apport sends the data).

Comment: I found a solution,

i could repair fglrx with this walkthrough

http://askubuntu.com/questions/55340/upgrade-ati-catalyst-control-center

(no guarantee)

Comment: Share you knowledge as an `answer to your own question` ;)

Comment: i can't, because i don't have enough points to answer my question. But i will edit my question itself. thank you for your respond

Comment: @Ello You'd be able to answer your own question soon. You're only prevented from doing so for, I think, about half a day. However, since *another question here on Ask Ubuntu* contains the answer, we should perhaps simply *close this as a duplicate of that question.* If we don't end up doing that, then you should still go ahead and post the answer here.